# Automatic uniqueidentifier during table design

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've created a new table and made column `id` the primary key and defined it as `uniqueidentifier`.

Is there a way during the tables design in SQL Server Management Studio to assign a rule that all new rows auto generate a new `uniqueidentifier` in the `id` column?

At the moment to make my form (made on Retool) write to the table I need to type out a random set of characters, essentially self creating my own `uniqueidentifier` which obviously isn't correct.

Comment: Use a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` and use `NEWID()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` (depending on your requirement) for the default value. I suggest, however, not using the table designer; it's quirky, flawed, and doesn't support complex logic. Learn to T-SQL for modifying your data and objects.

Comment: Just set a default value. Preferably using `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` instead of `NEWID()`. That generates a sequential GUID that doesn't cause the fragmentation a normal GUID would

Comment: *Why* did you use a GUID as a key though? A `bigint` IDENTITY column is more than large enough to handle any data amount.

Comment: That person was wrong, and `ID100000` is neither a bigint nor an IDENTITY, it's a string. Something that shouldn't be used. A numeric field with the IDENTITY constraing starts from the number *you* provide (by default 1)  and gets incremented automatically on every insert

Answer (score 3):

Avoid the designers, they've been [a complete and utter mess](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers) for 17 years. Do this in a query window:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.what
(
  id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL 
      CONSTRAINT DF_what_id DEFAULT(NEWSEQUENTIALID()),
      -- or NEWID() if you like page splits
  name nvarchar(128),
  CONSTRAINT PK_what PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT dbo.what(name) VALUES(N'hi'),(N'there');

SELECT id, name FROM dbo.what;
```

Output (yours will have different values for `id`):

> | id | name |
> | --- | --- |
> | 84c37c76-8c0e-ed11-ba5d-00163ef319ff | hi |
> | 85c37c76-8c0e-ed11-ba5d-00163ef319ff | there |

Comment: Compared to MySQL or Oracle designers though, they're NCC-1701. Yes, the old one but it's still 200 years in the future. Come to think of it, Montgomerry Scott will have been born 200 years from this year in 2222

Answer (score 0):

Easy, Just go properties window of the table see Table Designer and Select your primary key field (uniqueidentifier) from **Row GUID Column** dropdown.
Thats it.